# Using the cancellationToken without Task.Wait()

Tags: c#, winforms, task, cancellation, cancellation-token

I have a `winforms app` with a long running task and two buttons.
One button Start and one Stop.

A new task with a cancellation Token starts when I press the start button.
And if I press the Stop button the cancellation Token's Cancel Method gets called.

I want the UI to be usable during all the time so where do I put the try, catch block for this job. In all the examples I saw they put it around t.Wait();

But if I do that the UI freezes and that is the reason why I used a Task in the first place, to continue using the ui while doing the task. So where to put the try catch block without using Task.Wait.

### Start button:

```
 tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
   ct = tokenSource2.Token;
   t = new Task(doStart, ct);
   t.Start();
```

### Stop button:

```
tokenSource2.Cancel();
```

Comment: related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update doStart to handle the cancellation event and exit the task gracefully so you wouldn't need to use Wait at all e.g.

```
public void doStart(CancellationToken token)
{
    while(...)
    {
        ...
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could wait for the task result on another thread e.g.

```
Thread.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
{
    try
    {
        t.Wait();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that in the second case you're not stopping the task, you're just continuing on and doing something else or ignoring the task despite the fact that it's not done.  The first option is preferable, whenever it's possible.

Comment: @Servy I agree, however, the question was about how not to block the UI.

Comment: You "don't block the UI" by just doing nothing else and not waiting at all.

Comment: @Servy the code is just an example of handling the result on another thread, I am answering from my mobile so it's difficult to write full-blown code. The OP can update it or change it to suit. I do agree with your initial point though, the best solution would be the first one.

Comment: The second example introduces a 2nd thread just to watch the first... This is not how it should be done (-1). Continuations are made for this.

Comment: @usr a continuation is itself another task therefore I can only assume it is *also* running on another thread therefore I see no real difference. Although I agree that ContinueWith is probably the neater alternative.

Comment: @James the continuation only starts once the antecedent completes. A thread is only blocked why the continuation is doing useful work. Its execution logically starts after the `Wait` in your code sample completes.

Comment: @usr like I said I agree the continuation is the way to go (at least when using TPL). However, depending on how long a particular task may take using the thread pool to wait on a task to finish isn't exactly a *bad* solution like your perceiving it to be. Out with the TPL, it's probably considered the *recommended* way of doing this sort of thing.